# Sending a file and text in one message [Discord Bot] [Python]

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

This is the first post I've ever made here but I've been researching for about half an hour and I haven't found a solution. I am making a python discord bot and I've run into an issue. I want to send a picture and a text message in one message call. Here is my code.

```
...
await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('playerReport.png', content=m[:len(m)-1]))
...
```

This code works, however it sends the text with the picture under it. However, I want it to send the actual picture and then send the text. I was wondering if there was a way to flip them.

Now, I have tried doing it like this:

```
await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('playerReport.png'))
await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(m[:len(m)-1]))
```

but doing it like this allows messages to be stuck in between the picture and the actual text.

Does anyone know how I can send the picture and the text in that order in one message call?

Comment: What you are asking is sadly impossible. The official Discord applications will always show the text before the image if they are in the same message. The best thing you can do is send one message with an image and then sending a second message with the text.

Comment: @LuM Thanks. I guess I'll go the route of the 2 messages. Sad that I can't manipulate it that way. They should update it so I can. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Seperate file from message. I mean, variable file write in another line.

```
file = discord.File("file.xxx", filename = "filename.xxx")
await ctx.send("write message" ,file = file)
```

xxx is format file.